# Where I can found container configuration file?

Tags: docker

After the windows update one of the docker container lost port mapping configuration:
[Docker Desktop (for Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhSMt.png)

I tried to find where the docker keeps configs for each container but found only paths
where are these files re-created when the container starts

\wsl$\docker-desktop\mnt\host\wsl\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\

Does anybody know how to edit this information without re-creating the container?

Comment: Why not simply re-create the container? In almost all cases that's the correct solution.

Comment: TO echo @larsks comment, simply remove the container from the docker desktop dashboard and start a new on from the image.